# Reactjs deleting item by ID

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a problem with my reactjs project.

I am trying to create a table with database data with add, delete, edit and sort options. Adding data is already done. Delete option is not done successfully, because I can delete row only by entering id manually and pressing button. I want to make button for each row to delete the records. now I have this :

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component{

  state = {
    carowner: [],
    owner:
    {

        first_name:'',
        last_name:'',
        phone:'',
        email:''
    },
    delowner:
    {
      owner_id:''
    }
  }
componentDidMount()
{
 this.getOwners();
}
getOwners = _ =>{
  fetch('http://localhost:4000/owners')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => this.setState({ carowner: response.data }))
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
}
addOwner = _ =>
{
    const {owner} = this.state;
    fetch(`http://localhost:4000/owners/add?first_name=${owner.first_name}&last_name=${owner.last_name}&phone=${owner.phone}&email=${owner.email}`)
    .then(this.getOwners)
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
}

delOwner = _ =>
{
  const {delowner} = this.state;
  fetch(`http://localhost:4000/owners/delete?owner_id=${delowner.owner_id}`)
  .then(this.getOwners)
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
}


renderCarOwner = ({owner_id,first_name,last_name,phone,email}) => <tr key={owner_id}><td>{owner_id}</td><td>{first_name}</td><td>{last_name}</td><td>{phone}</td><td>{email}</td><td><button onClick={() => {this.delOwner()}}>va</button></td></tr>
render()
{
  const {carowner,owner,delowner} = this.state;
return(
  <div className="centerblock">
  <div>
  <input value={owner.first_name} onChange={e => this.setState({owner:{...owner, first_name: e.target.value}})}/>
    <input value={owner.last_name} onChange={e => this.setState({owner:{...owner, last_name: e.target.value}})}/>
    <input value={owner.phone} onChange={e => this.setState({owner:{...owner, phone: e.target.value}})}/>
    <input value={owner.email} onChange={e => this.setState({owner:{...owner, email: e.target.value}})}/>
    <button onClick={this.addOwner}>Add owner</button>


  </div>
  <table >
  <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Action</th> 
                </tr>
{carowner.map(this.renderCarOwner)}
</table>
  </div>
);
}
}
export default App;
```

field for manual id enter

```
 <input value={delowner.owner_id} onChange={e => this.setState({delowner:{...owner, owner_id: e.target.value}})}/>
```

Screen of website view:

[image: screen of website view]

Comment: now when i press "va" button the situation is -
http://prntscr.com/prvmlg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id of the Owner to be deleted can be passed as an input as below

```
<td><button onClick={(evt) => {this.delOwner(evt,delowner.owner_id)}}>va</button></td>
```

and the function can be modified to delete the owner

```
delOwner = (evt,owner_id) =>
{

  fetch(`http://localhost:4000/owners/delete?owner_id=${owner_id}`)
  .then(this.getOwners)
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
}
```

Comment: Line 49:227:  'delowner' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: Thank you, deleted delowner completely, now it works ! 
u are awesome :)